# How to Refresh Page from Grand Child popup using JavaScript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have main Aspx page ( A) from that i am calling popup window (B) while closing popup B i am calling another popup page (C) while closing page (C) i need to refresh main aspx page (A). at that moment Popup B will not be there. 
usually we will refresh by windows.opener.location.reload();
but in this case opener will be Null

can anyone suggest the way please.